# Struts2 file upload max size

Tags: struts2

I need to upload files upto 10 MB.I used the following  .In my struts.xml i configured like as follows.

```
<action name="doUpload" class="com.example.UploadAction">
<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
    <param name="maximumSize">20971520</param>
</interceptor-ref>
</action>
```

I did not configured any where other than this.I am getting the following error.

**the request was rejected because its size (2102840) exceeds the configured maximum (2097152)**

Can any one suggest me what might be the reason.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put this in your struts.xml file

```
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="30000000" />
```

See http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/file-upload.html#FileUpload-AdvancedConfiguration.

Updated link -
https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/file-upload.html#file-size-limits

Answer (score 2):

Also check your container configuration. Tomcat itself, for example, has a maxPostSize parameter which, if not set defaults to 2097152 (2Mb).

Check how to configure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10848475/1657465):

```xml
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           maxPostSize="67589953" />
```

Answer (score 0):

put this code on your `strtus.xml:`

```
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="50000000" />
```

where value denotes your file size limit . if you want to extend the limit you can change the value as well . hope it helps