# How to fix org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase and SizeLimitExceededException in Struts 2

Tags: file-upload, configuration, struts2

I am trying to upload a file in my application. The file size is of 2055 kb. After uploading the file. It throws an exception is:

```
04-Feb-2016 15:42:41.141 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-78] com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.info Unable to find 'struts.multipart.saveDir' property setting. Defaulting to javax.servlet.context.tempdir
04-Feb-2016 15:42:41.203 WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-78] com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn Request exceeded size limit!"
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (2104281) exceeds the configured maximum (2097152)
```

I am using Struts Framework.

Comment: What is the server you use, Tomcat ?

Comment: *rejected because its size (2104281) exceeds the configured maximum (2097152)* - Configure maximum.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Struts2 file upload max size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121014/struts2-file-upload-max-size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts2 allows to configure the limits for uploaded file(s).

> The Struts 2 `default.properties` file defines several settings that affect the behavior of file uploading. You may find in necessary to change these values. The names and default values are:
>
> ```
> struts.multipart.parser=jakarta
> struts.multipart.saveDir=
> struts.multipart.maxSize=2097152
> ```

Note, without `0` at the end.

You can change this by setting a constant to increase a request limit

```xml
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="20971520" />
```

> Please remember that the `struts.multipart.maxSize` is the size limit of the whole request, which means when you uploading multiple files, the sum of their size must be below the `struts.multipart.maxSize`!

There's also a limit on individual file that you can change by overriding the action config

```xml
<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
   <param name="maximumSize">20971520</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

More in formation about [File Upload](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/file-upload.html) you can find on the docs page.

Comment: I used <constant name= "struts.multipart.maxSize"  value= "10000000"> in my struts.xml page. Now i can able to upload file more than 2Mb.