# FileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Connection terminated as request was larger than 10485760

Tags: java, struts, apache-commons

I am using apache library for uploading file. File size < 10MB works as expected but when i upload more than 10MB file then it shows me error as

```
"org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. UT000020: Connection terminated as request was larger than 10485760".
```

I am using `struts 1.2`, `java 8`, `commons-fileupload-1.4.jar`, `wildfly 12`.

Wildfly has default upload file size as 10485760 so i changed it to 25485760 so that it can except 25MB file but still same error.

Actually i am looking for upload file with at least < 1GB file.

I am open to use any other library which fits in my above configurations.

Please help me out on this.

Comment: What kind of application are you using ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Struts2 file upload max size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121014/struts2-file-upload-max-size)

Comment: Hi Anish, Thanks for quick response. adding "<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="30000000" />" showing compile time error in struts 1.2. so do i need to upgrade my struts 1.2. to 2 version.

Comment: What errors are shown ? Can you share that ?

Comment: If you want, you can upgrade to Struts 2.0.