# Java EE Request parameters missing

Tags: forms, jakarta-ee, submit, tomcat6

When I submit a form (via post) to a Servlet, with a `<textarea>` that contains roughly 2 MB of text, the `HttpRequest` object contains no parameters.  When the `<textarea>` has only 2 KB of text, all of the parameters are in the `HttpRequest` object.

I've tried changing the `FORM ENCTYPE` to the three allowed values, to no avail.

I'm using Apache Tomcat 6.0.29, Java 5.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947683/httprequest-maximum-allowable-size-in-tomcat

Comment: I also needed to set the form's **enctype** to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.  With both in place, everything works perfectly.  Thank you very much for your help!