# How to set the maximum receive limit for HTTP file transfer using Tomcat

Tags: http, tomcat, tomcat6, tomcat5.5

Hi I am sending and receiving files through HTTP and i am able to send a file size of more than 4mb, but in the receiver end I am unable to receive a file size of more than 4mb and hence I am getting an timeout exception at the sender end. I know that we can set maxpostsize in server.xml toset maximum post size for HTTP request. Do we have any such settings to increase the receiving limit.

Comment: do you get error in your web application? or in wap deployment?

Comment: can you post the full stack trace exception?

Comment: Hi User 2511414 and Fmodos thanks a lot for your responce. My scenario goes like this. 

We are doing file transfers using HTTP and the files are secured using AS2 protocal bu the issue is no where related to the AS2. We are using sockets to send the files though the HTTP port. It was a third party tool which is used to send and receive files so we are not aware of the code they have used. We can only edit the configuration files i.e., server.xml to handle this.

Comment: We initially had an issue were the file sizes were limited to scertain mb's for SEND. i have handled this by increasing the bytes value in the tag maxPostSize, but now we are facing problems in the receiver side were sockets is unable to receive a file size of greater than 4mb.
 
So I assumed that this can be handled by increasing some parameter value in server.xml. Kindly assist if you have dealt with this situation before.
 
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: you could perhaps look at this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10848475/1547266