# Primefaces+SpringBoot large file upload failed

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload, primefaces

As simple as it can be, but it is not working

upload.xhtml

```
<p:fileUpload mode="advanced" skinSimple="true" auto="true" fileUploadListener="#{upload.fileUploadListener}" />
```

method

```
public void fileUploadListener(FileUploadEvent e){
        // Get uploaded file from the FileUploadEvent
        this.file = e.getFile();
        // Print out the information of the file
        System.out.println("Uploaded File Name Is :: "+file.getFileName()+" :: Uploaded File Size :: "+file.getSize());
    }
```

[image]

My environment is

Sprintboot - 2.0.2
PrimeFaces 6.x
Mojarra 2.3.4 
PrimeFaces Extensions 6.2.4

Comment: What application server are you using? See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564683/how-to-limit-uploaded-filesize-in-tomcat-servlet

Comment: Does the server log something?

Comment: Tomcat - Springboot default @JasperdeVries

Comment: Nope, debugger point does not hit no logs no errors @Selaron

Comment: Is there an error in the javascript [console] tab? Looks like jquery wants to tell something.

Comment: Spring boot has a 1MB maximum upload by default. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271484/spring-upload-file-size-limit to change your Spring Boot config to allow bigger files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring upload file size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271484/spring-upload-file-size-limit)

Comment: @Melloware that's correct

Answer (score 0):

It is not a duplicate because of "Primefaces" term in the question. Sending large files is a matter of both client and server sides. On server-side, you have to do as shown into
[Spring upload file size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271484/spring-upload-file-size-limit). On client-side (the Primefaces based "view") you have to do like shown at [fileUpload component's documentation](http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/chunked.xhtml?jfwid=d47ba), by adding *maxChunkSize* attribute to your code:

```
<p:fileUpload mode="advanced" maxChunkSize="1000000"
              auto="true" skinSimple="true"                  
              listener="#{upload.fileUploadListener}" />
```