# HttpURLConnection not timing out

Tags: java, tcp

I have discovered some weird behaviour of `HttpURLConnection` in Java. I have java client that sets up http connection, sends data to java service and returns response. During test of my application I tried to check timeout mechanism (both set up for 5000 ms), so I killed java service with `kill -SIGSTOP` and I expected read/connect timeouts on client side. However, there is no timeouts on client side, connection is created, data is written and connection is freezed for ~3 minutes, then `IOException` is thrown with `"Error writing to server"` message. Is there any mistake in configuration of `HttpUrlConnection`?

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection(config.getProxy());
    try {
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

        stream.write(data);
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();

        return new response(connection);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log("{send} exception occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        return new response(connection);
    } finally {
        if (null != connection) {
            logger.log("{send} closing connection: " + connection);
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: 'Error writing to server' is not a Java error message. Sounds like yours to me. What was the real message?

Comment: I think it is Java message, f.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921426/error-writing-to-server