# How to mitigate Oversized XML Attacks for a Spring Webservice

Tags: java, security, jaxb, spring-ws

Using spring-ws with JAXB as our stack for SOAP-webservices I want to secure them against `"Oversized Xml"-attacks`. In CXF I know there is the possibility to defend against most of these attacks using the following properties:

```
org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements
org.apache.cxf.stax.maxElementDepth
org.apache.cxf.stax.maxAttributeCount
org.apache.cxf.stax.maxAttributeSize    
org.apache.cxf.stax.maxTextLength
org.apache.cxf.stax.maxElementCount
```

However I have not found anything equal in the spring-stack. Is there a way to mitigate this kind of attacks?

Comment: If nothing else helped try limiting the size of HTTP requests: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947683/httprequest-maximum-allowable-size-in-tomcat

Comment: I already thought of that, but according to [this site](http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13247001/XML%20Attribute%20Blowup) a file with only 90k could cause the parser to do 50,000,000 basic operations. So I thought of using something like the things available in cxf.

Comment: is it the performance bottleneck of the system? has it been measured?

Comment: No, up to this point it is no performance issue and it could be a solution to limit the size of the requests. But I still think that it is just a symptom cure and hope there's something equivalent  to cxf's properties.

Comment: Maybe JAXB can be replaced with CFX in Spring: https://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately our customer has a strict policy regarding the used frameworks. :-( I suppose I'll fall back to the sizelimit approach.