# Highcharts export server for large datasize does not work

Tags: highcharts, phantomjs

I have configured highcharts export server successfully. The jpeg option has never worked but other options like png, pdf, svg works fine. Is there some additional configuration needed for jpeg export? I get this error

```
Timeout converting SVG, is your file this big, or maybe you have a syntax error in the javascript callback?
```

Also when the data size is too big then none option works. I have changed the default setting as below:

```
readTimeout = 60000; connectTimeout = 60000; maxTimeout = 65000; poolSize = 100; maxWait = 6000; retentionTime = 60000
```

What setting i have to change so that the export happens fine?
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What export server are you running? Batik? Java/PhantomJS? NodeJS? If PhatomJS you can increase the java app servers data size - method varies depending on the server.

Comment: java/phantomjs. how can i increase server data size. example would be helpful.

Comment: For Tomcat see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947683/httprequest-maximum-allowable-size-in-tomcat

Comment: i modified server.xml to <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" maxPostSize="67589953" maxHttpHeaderSize="67589953"/> but it did not solve the issue i am facing.

Comment: Does your export work if you direct it to export.highcharts.com instead of your internal export server?

Comment: for graph with smaller data set it works pointing to export.highcharts.com. Even the same works with my internal server when data set is small. Only with large dataset it does not work.

Comment: But does your large data set work pointing at highchart's export URL? Is it only your self-hosted export server that cant do large charts?

Comment: For highchart export server I get the error "413 Request Entity Too Large" when i try with large dataset. thats why i decide to have my own export server.

Comment: Wow, okay - how many data points are in this chart?

Comment: around 7000 data points.

Comment: It looks like phantomJS hits the timeout. Could you try to change [`TIMEOUT`](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-export-server/blob/master/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js#L25) in `highcharts-convert.js` file?

Comment: I get the below error.  [ERROR] [http-nio-8080-exec-1 07:45:23] (SVGConverter.java:requestServer:142) java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out