# Specify the maximum size of the request on Java Tomcat server

Tags: java, http, tomcat

I am using a tomcat server and making POST requests to it. My requests are quite big in size, say up to 10 MB. Is there a way I can increase the max request size?

I am not sending files and it is not a multipart request. I have tried ways that have been discussed earlier but they have been not of much use to me.

Comment: A 10MB HTTP request that does not include file? What's the request `Content-Type`? It sounds like an XY problem (http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: See the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947683/httprequest-maximum-allowable-size-in-tomcat

Comment: I want to send the content of the file in the request but I forcibly don't want it to be a file request. Server is not able to handle such large request. Is there any way I can increase the size of the request that the server is handling? @shaochuancs

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your request, what you need is to increase the default tomcat limits. You then have to open "server.xml" file in conf folder of Tomcat, then search for <Connector> element, and add/edit attribute "maxPostSize". Then restart tomcat.

E.g. this is one I use in a development environment:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
     URIEncoding="UTF-8"
     compression="on" 
     compressionMinSize="2048"
     connectionTimeout="20000"
     maxPostSize="52428800"
     redirectPort="8443" />
```

Hoping this can help.