# How to upload files over 100 MB to Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, file-upload, multipart, large-files

I'm facing trouble while uploading large files to the server for my project. I have modified maxPostSize and maxHttpHeaderSize in server.xml as suggested in this  [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947683/httprequest-maximum-allowable-size-in-tomcat) but it's showing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. What to do?

Comment: Have you consider using [Apache Commons FileUpload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html) ? A good API, easy to use. Don't think 100MB file will be a problem.

Comment: @john It's much easier to use the servlet-provided API to accept uploads (because the API is simpler AND the container provides the mechanism to do it so the application does not need to package that dependency). Oddly enough, Tomcat uses commons-fileupload behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets011.htm). In particular, you're interested in the `maxFileSize` parameter, which you can set either with annotations or xml.

Directly from the link above,

```
@MultipartConfig(location="/tmp", fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024,
maxFileSize=1024*1024*5, maxRequestSize=1024*1024*5*5)
```

or

```
<multipart-config>
    <location>/tmp</location>
    <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
    <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
    <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

So for example, you can annotate your servlet like so:

```
@MultipartFileConfig( options )
public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet {

    ...
```

or add the equivalent xml in the config if using xml.