# Jenkins File Paramater size limit in upload

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I was not able to find anywhere information about Jenkins' [File Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) limit size.
Empirically, we had problems with 100MB files.
Does anyone knows what's the limitation, and where it's possible to change it?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to edit the jenkins web.xml file to increase upload limit with

```
<max-file-size>500000000</max-file-size>
```

the value is in Bytes

see this example
[HttpRequest maximum allowable size in tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947683/httprequest-maximum-allowable-size-in-tomcat)

Comment: The link in your answer is broken - 404 not found.