# Tomcat throwing error when header size is 8192 chars (8KB)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I am getting Request Header too long exception for one of my header in request in spring boot app. I am using embedded tomcat 9.0.13 with spring boot 2.1.1.
Header value in request:

X-CertChain: `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`

Its not even 8192 chars long as per the default size of tomcat. But still it throws error.
Error Description:

org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor service
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request header is too large
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:718)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseHeader(Http11InputBuffer.java:865)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseHeaders(Http11InputBuffer.java:563)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:311)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I customize it in application.props file to server.max-http-header-size=10000, then its start working. Any issue with header value? Any other reason?

Comment: The header length is the size of all header data including all attributes, thier names, line feeds etc. Is this how you have calcualted the length?

Comment: @Codo: I am calculating only the value as shown above. Not including the key. But when I remove one character from the value it starts working. So dont know why 8192 characters are not working. But 8191 works.

Comment: That's not how the Tomcat parameter works. It includes all names and values. BTW: Your example value is only 5712 characters long.

Comment: @Codo: Still its not working. Tomcat says max size is 8192.

Comment: @Codo: Yes you are right. Actually there are other headers in my request and including this one and the size is going beyond 8192 chars. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

How about change maxHttpHeaderSize attribute in server.xml?

Below is the reference.

[HttpRequest maximum allowable size in tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947683/httprequest-maximum-allowable-size-in-tomcat)